pre-trained model embeddings from Universal Sentence Encoder
I am trying to load pretrained embeddings from Universal Sentence Encoder on TF-Hub. It seems to work only on keras v. 2.15.0. I am seeking help with its implementation on keras v 3.0.5
FYI - I did implement a class wrapper as suggested in the error below, but it still fails. This time it complained about type string being unknown.
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "jax"  # "jax" or "tensorflow" or "torch" 

import keras_nlp
import keras
import keras.backend as K

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding


USE_model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
embedding_layer = hub.KerasLayer(USE_model_url,
                                 input_shape=[],
                                 dtype=tf.string,
                                 name="Universal_sentence_encoder"
)

In the following model definition the call to embedding_layer()
Fails for keras v. 3.0.5 
Works for keras v. 2.15.0
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
pretrained_embeddings = embedding_layer(inputs) <--- Error on this line


Error:
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'Universal_sentence_encoder' (type KerasLayer).
Binding inputs to tf.function failed due to A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function. A KerasTensor is a symbolic placeholder for a shape and dtype, used when constructing Keras Functional models or Keras Functions. You can only use it as input to a Keras layer or a Keras operation (from the namespaces keras.layers and keras.operations). You are likely doing something like:
x = Input(...)
...
tf_fn(x)  # Invalid.

What you should do instead is wrap tf_fn in a layer:
class MyLayer(Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        return tf_fn(x)

x = MyLayer()(x)

. Received args: (<KerasTensor shape=(None,), dtype=string, sparse=None, name=keras_tensor>,) and kwargs: {} for signature: (inputs: TensorSpec(shape=<unknown>, dtype=tf.string, name=None)).
Call arguments received by layer 'Universal_sentence_encoder' (type KerasLayer): 
• inputs=<KerasTensor shape=(None,), dtype=string, sparse=None, name=keras_tensor> 
• training=None


I just modified this question as I noted it works on keras v.2.15.0 but not the version I was working on (3.0.5)
